# parsing a pdf file with clickable contents page

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, pdf, pdf-parsing

Let's say we have a pdf file that has clickable contents page. (I am talking about chapters and subchapters)
How can that certain file be parsed in C# and how can an application realize whether the pdf it is reading has or has not chapters/contents etc?

This is a link to a pdf without clickable table of contents
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1EbI-EMJxmkODE1Mm5WbFpEdXc
I did not seem to find a pdf with clickable table of contents but I found a guide on how to do it here
http://everythingyoumightneed.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-create-pdf-with-clickable-links.html

So my question is: How can an app differentiate which is which and how can the one with clickable links be parsed?

Comment: iTextSharp is one of the many PDF libraries you may want to consider for PDF analysis. But what do you consider a PDF without chapter or content, what are your criteria?

Comment: @mkl Well what I know about is two pdf styles. One is with clickable contents-chapters, and the other is simple text (that might include a page of contents but are not clickable) I want a way to define whether there are clickable contents or not, and how to parse those contents

Comment: Maybe you should supply sample documents for both cases. As a first hunch, though, i think you either mean outlines or annotations. Both can easily be checked for using iTextSharp or any other serious PDF library.

Comment: Where to upload a file to share it here?

Comment: Stack overflow only offers image upload, so you have to employ a different file sharing service. Please don't select one which requires downloaders to register.

Comment: @mkl
added links to original question

Comment: I don't seem to be allowed to access the googledocs document. The howto you referenced seems to indicate, though, that you are indeed talking about Link Annotations, not outlines. Checking whether a file has any link annotations is fairly easy, you just iterate over the annotations of all pages and check whether any of them are link annotations with destinations. But you then do not yet know whether those links are located on a contents list or not. Can you be sure that any links present are on contents lists only? If not, how can contents lists be distinhuished in the documents?

Comment: the pdf you have not acces to (don't know why, maybe it's a temp thing, anws) is a simple pdf, now about the link annotations you speak off (I do not know the difference between outlines) is what I am talking about I think. Here is the deal. I am creating an app that parses pdf files. I want it to work with all pdf types as they are intended to be. For example if they have clickable contents table I want the to remain the same

Comment: Well, actually I would propose you work on your project step by step. The first step is parsing the text. The second step is interpreting annotations, i.e. interactive features like links and forms. You only should remember text positions in your first step to match text and annotations in the second step.

Comment: That is indeed a good idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not dissimilar to trying to figure out where paragraphs and columns are in PDF files; PDF doesn't typically label a table of contents page as such. So even with a PDF library (such as iTextSharp pointed out by mkl), this will not be a trivial task.

With such a library, you will be able to see the pages in the PDF file and the text on the pages. However, if this is a book for example, the table of contents page may be the first, second, third or xth page in the PDF file because of various other pages appearing in front of it (cover, second cover, copyright, tributes, you name it...).

So an algorithm to discover whether there is a table of content would have to be able to discover it somewhere in the first x pages of the PDF file. As there are no standard tags highlighting the text in the table of contents, this would have to be done through analysis of the format of the text on that page.

There are two things that could be of help (if they are available):

1) In many PDF files the items in a table are contents are like you say clickable. So you could look in the PDF file and try to find the first page that contains a lot of hyperlinked items.

2) In many PDF file the table of contents is mirrored in bookmarks. So you could also examine the bookmarks structure and see if you can use that to figure out how many chapters there are in the book.

Keep in mind that both of these features are optional and not standardizes if they are present.

Comment: Well what I know about is two pdf styles. One is with clickable contents-chapters, and the other is simple text (that might include a page of contents but are not clickable) I want a way to define whether there are clickable contents or not, and how to parse those contents. I think you already defined that but please be more informantive as I am a noob and need more help

Answer (score 1):

Since PDF is an binary format you'll have to use a pdf-library like pdflib  in order to read pdf-files.

[pdfLib](http://www.pdflib.com)

also you may want to check out this CodeProject site for some examples
[Converting PDF to Text in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12445/Converting-PDF-to-Text-in-C)

Comment: this is a copy paste from another answer, I need something more specefici (probably your answer but I need some explanation here aswell)